# Sortable, draggable, orderable table + mvc not updating order correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I'm trying to add an orderable table to my view. The sorting works when doing it in the View New.cshtml. It uses [jQuerys sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/). If I add some instructions (1-5 in this case) I can move them around thanks to the sortable script. But when I try to add a new instruction after the reordering, the order change from:

[image]

to

[image]

I guess it has something to do with the hidden form

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number, new { @id = "Number"})
```

It needs to update its value when I reorder the fields in the sortable table.

What am I missing here?

RecipeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create(NewRecipeViewModel viewModel, string command)
{

//...more code...

    var instructionList = new List<Instruction>();

    if (viewModel.Recipe.Instructions != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.Recipe.Instructions.Count; i++)
        {
            var instruction = new Instruction
            {
                Id = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions[i].Id,
                Name = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions[i].Name,
                Number = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number

            };
            instructionList.Add(instruction);
        }
    }

    if (command.Equals("AddInstruction"))
    {
        var instruction = new Instruction
        {
            Name = viewModel.NewInstruction.Name,
            Number = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions.Count + 1
        };

        recipe.Instructions.Add(instruction);
        viewModel.Recipe = recipe;

        return View("New", viewModel);
    }

//...more code...
}
```

New.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 170px;">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
        Lägg till instruktion:
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewInstruction.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 300px;">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <button type="submit" name="command" value="AddInstruction" class="btn btn-primary">Add instruction</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 100px;">

    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
        Instructions:
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover pagin-table" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <thead>
                <tr bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                    <th>Order:</th>
                    <th>Instruction:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="sortable">
                @if (Model.Recipe.Instructions != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Recipe.Instructions.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Id)
                            <td class="order">
                                @Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number, new { @id = "Number"})
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Name
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Name)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#sortable').sortable({
                 update : function(event, ui) { 
                     $('td.order').each(function(index) {
                        var order = index + 1;
                        $(this).find('span').text(order);
                        $(this).find('.Number').val(order);
                     });
                 }
             });
     });
 </script
```

**EDIT:**
Added

```
instructionList.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.Number.CompareTo(s2.Number));
```

to RecipeController.cs. The rest is credit to Stephen Muecke.

RecipeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create(NewRecipeViewModel viewModel, string command)
{

//...more code...

    var instructionList = new List<Instruction>();

    if (viewModel.Recipe.Instructions != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.Recipe.Instructions.Count; i++)
        {
            var instruction = new Instruction
            {
                Id = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions[i].Id,
                Name = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions[i].Name,
                Number = viewModel.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number

            };
            instructionList.Add(instruction);
        }
        instructionList.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.Number.CompareTo(s2.Number));
    }

//...more code...
}
```

New.cshtml

```
 @* More code *@
 <td class="order">
      <span>@Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number</span>
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number, new {@class = "Number"})
 </td>

 @* More code *@    

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#sortable').sortable({
                 update : function(event, ui) { 
                     $('td.order').each(function(index) {
                        var order = index + 1;
                        $(this).find('span').text(order);
                        $(this).find('.Number').val(order);
                     });
                 }
             });
     });
 </script
```

Comment: Remove the `new { @id = "Number"}` - your creating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. Are you wanting to update the value of `Number` in the scripts `update` function?

Comment: I want to update the Number property in my controller when I reorder the fields in the table of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector in the `update` function is incorrect and would return `undefined` (you are missing the `#` (id selector) and in anycase the `$` creates a jQuery object, so it would be `.val(...)`, not `value=...`.

However using `$('#Number').val(index + 1)` will not work correctly since it would only ever update the first element with `id="Number". Duplicate`id` attributes are invalid html.

Use a class name and relative selectors instead. Change the html to

```
<td class="order">
    <span>@Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number</span>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number, new { @class = "Number"})
</td>
```

and then the script to

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    update : function(event, ui) { 
        $('td.order').each(function(index) {
            var order = index + 1;
            $(this).find('span').text(order );
            $(this).find('.Number').val(order );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! Updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, change `Model` to your projected variable `m` within your 'Html.HiddenFor()' HTML helpers.

```
<tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Id)
    <td class="order">
        @Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Number, new { @id = "Number"})
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Recipe.Instructions[i].Name
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipe.Instructions[i].Name)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything I'm afraid.